# Script fails when using python-shell Node.js package

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, opencv, npm

So I'm having a pretty odd issue. I have a python script whose function is to analyze an image and produce an output string. I decided to implement this script into the backend of my NodeJS server using the package 'python-shell.' The funny thing is, this script works perfectly when it's run on its own. It is able to analyze the image and produce the output string. However, when I attempt to have the 'python-shell' package run it, there is an error that is produced (related to the python code). I've tested and the python-shell runs the same version of python as is used at the terminal, so I'm not 100% sure why this issue is occurring. For reference, the below code is how I'm running the script:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pythonshell = require('python-shell');
pythonshell.defaultOptions = { scriptPath: '/path/to/myscript.py' };

var outputString = '';
var options = {args: ['-p', '/path/to/image.jpg']}
var pyshell = new pythonshell('myscript.py', options);

pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script
    console.log(message);
    outputString = message;
});

pyshell.end(function(err) {
    // This is where the error occurs
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Picture analysis complete');
    console.log('outputString: ' + outputString);
});
```

Again, when the script is manually run (i.e. python myscript.py -p image.jpg), it runs perfectly fine. I can include the code in myscript.py, although I doubt that will help as it doesn't seem to be an error with the actual python code. The image is analyzed using several packages including OpenCV (and the produced error is, I believe, based off that). Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

change the default path
`pythonshell.defaultOptions = { scriptPath: '/path/to/myscript.py' };`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. I already have the correct path to the script, and the script runs: there is just an error that is produced while running the script that is not there when it is run manually.

Comment: It seems fairly irrelevant, seeing as how the error is not present when the script is run on it's own, but the error says: ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
Which as stated above is related to some of the code that is analyzing the image.